# Execute Jenkins Pipeline from inside DSL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I do have a pipeline, p1, configured with 3 parameters, param1 as ChoiceParam, and param2 and param3 as runParameters, that retrieve different build-ids to pass them as versions.

I do also have annother pipeline, p2, from which i'd like to run p1.
p2 does also have the same parameters configured, so, inside the dsl, i need to call p1 with params1,params2,params3 , as params should be inherited in p2

But i'm unable, as i've tried any single way i can think of.
Can anyone help me ?

```
p2:
build() {
    job('p1')
    parameters([[$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param1', value:${param1}],
                [$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param2', value:${param2}],
                [$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param3', value:${param3}]
    ])
}
```

Then, also tried

```
p2:
build(job:'p1', parameters: ([[$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param1', value:${param1}],
            [$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param2', value:${param2}],
            [$class:'StringParameterValue', name:'param3', value:${param3}]
]))
```

with no success. Any help, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to define `p1` as a full, separate job ? I don't think it's a good practice to chain pipelines jobs like we used to do with freestyle jobs.
Instead you should probably load another pipeline file containing your `p1` tasks, and then just call `p1`'s defined function from `p2`. Here is [a good example from the doc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading).

Basically what you need to do is define your `p1` as a pipeline file `p1.groovy` :

```
def p1Actions(param1, param2, param3) {
    // Do whatever p1 does with your 3 params
}

return this;
```

And then just call it from `p2` :

```
pipeline = load 'p1.groovy'
pipeline.p1Actions()
```

And if you want p1 to be reusable from other jobs than `p2`, just push it into its own SCM repo, and just add an SCM checkout to previous example, just before loading the script. By the way this step is also very well covered [in the documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading).